# Module including in rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I have written constant.rb in lib/ folder for my rails app.To use that in ActiveRecord, I have written `ActiveRecord::Base.extends Constant` in constant.rb and it is working. But I don't know how to use the same in ActionController, I tried `ActionController::Base.extends Constant` But It is not worked. Pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's typo... you wrote the plural but actually it's singular [`extend`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Object.html#method-i-extend).

A few tips:

- Constant may not be a good name for your Module maybe call more specific like AppConstant.
- You shouldn't put this into your `lib/constant.rb`, it's cleaner to create a new initializer like

**config/initializers/constants.rb**

```
require 'app_constant'
ActiveRecord::Base.extend AppConstant
ActiveController::Base.extend AppConstant
```

maybe there's an even better way: put the `extend AppConstant` into your `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

Answer (score 2):

A simple mistake.

You want `ActionController::Base.extend(Constant)`.

Note: `extend` not `extend*s*`